# Vector Integrals: can I take out the vector outside of the integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, calculus

Question:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

The notation used is: $(x,y,z)$ is for rectangular coordinates, $(\rho,\varphi,z)$ for cylindrical coordinates and $(r,\theta,\varphi)$ for spherical coordinates. ${ { \hat { a }  } }_{ ρ }$ represents the unit vector for $\rho$ (same applies to $x, y, z$ and other coordinates).

In part a, can't you take out ${ { \hat { a }  } }_{ ρ }$ from the integral? I'm having trouble understanding how ${ { \hat { a }  } }_{ ρ }$ depends on ϕ. ${ { \hat { a }  } }_{ ρ }$ is defined as ρ=1, ϕ=0 and z=0. Aren't all of these constants that do not rely on ϕ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that. The unit vector $\hat{a}_{\rho}$ does not mean: $\rho=1$, $\phi=0$, $z=0$. $\hat{a}_{\rho}$ actually depends on $\phi$ as it's $\left( cos\phi,sin\phi,0 \right)$.